# sql database search record in database using listview

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

Good day. How can i put a search in my program in c#? It would search record from SQL database then display the records in listview. thanks you

i've tried add this line of code in my program but an error message appears:
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection MySqlConnection;
    SqlDataReader m_dr;
    SqlCommand command;
    DataTable p_table = new DataTable();

    MySqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=A-A-PC\\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=lights and sounds;User ID=sa;Password=itexpert;");

    MySqlConnection.Open();
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory  WHERE package='" + textBox7.Text + "'", MySqlConnection);
    m_dr = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (m_dr.HasRows)
    {
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);
        p_table.Clear();
        SqlDataAdapter m_d = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from inventory", MySqlConnection);

        m_d.Fill(p_table);
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < p_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow drow = p_table.Rows[i];
            if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["id"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["package"].ToString());
                lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["number"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are you asking for the c# code for a search method, or the code for an SQL query?

Comment: I've tried to code but it does not work. I am asking for the c# code for a search method. i would like my program to have search bar.

Comment: Your question covers a very large scope. Which specific part do you need help with ? The SQL query, the data access, the listview ? Please narrow it down to one specific question. We're not going to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: i've posted my codes. please check

Comment: I don't believe you need to re-establish your SQLconnection in every command. Also, if you haven't already, don't forget to close your connection afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things that may be causing issues or conflicts. They may be unnecessary but it just neatens your code.

1. Create the SQL Command object inside your SQL Connection:

   ```
   MySQLConnection = new SQLConnection(/*Connection string here*/);
   command = MySQLConnection.CreateCommand();
   ```
2. Use a `try{} catch{}` block. This will catch on any errors and show you what is going on if you follow the code in debug mode. eg.

   ```
   try
   {
   //your code here
   }
   catch(SqlException e){ Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
   finally
   { if (MySQLConnectrion != null)
       {
           MySQLConnection.Close();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is lacking "using" block. Use the using block to make sure of the disposal of the connection. Like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    Sqlmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sqlmd);
   //code goes here...
}
```